# Select pairs of (http requests, http responses) from clickhouse database

Tags: sql, clickhouse

My Clickhouse database contains records of different sysdig events (file descriptor protocol is either tcp or udp). What I am trying to do, is to associate each http request with its corresponding http response, namely to build pairs of http requests/http responses. There is one way to know if two records can be paired, that is if they are contiguous when using the ORDER BY clause. Example:

```
select fd_l4proto,syscall_type, event_num, event_buffer
from my_db
where (syscall_type='recv_from' 
or syscall_type='send_to')
and event_buffer NOT LIKE ''
ORDER BY event_num
```

Gives us something like:
[image]

In the example mentioned above, we can see that the record with the event_num=278 should be associated with the event_num=285, and so on...

My question is, how can I create such pairs of http requests/responses knowing that they are contiguous in the query's result ?

Comment: What if there are several `send_to` without `recv_from` ?

Comment: There should not be, sysdig normally records every event that happens on the network layer. Guess that should not be something to consider in this case

Answer (score 1):

```sql
create table my_db ( syscall_type String, event_num Int64, event_buffer String) 
Engine=Memory;

insert into my_db values ('recv_from', 278, '..recv_from..278');
insert into my_db values ('send_to', 285, '..send_to..285');
insert into my_db values ('recv_from', 303, '...recv_from..303');
insert into my_db values ('send_to', 313, '...send_to..313');


SELECT
    syscall_type,
    event_num,
    event_buffer,
    prev.1 AS recv_syscall_type,
    prev.2 AS recv_event_num,
    prev.3 AS recv_event_buffer
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        any(tuple(*)) OVER w AS prev
    FROM my_db
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY event_num ASC Rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
)
WHERE syscall_type = 'send_to'

┌─syscall_type─┬─event_num─┬─event_buffer────┬─recv_syscall_type─┬─recv_event_num─┬─recv_event_buffer─┐
│ send_to      │       285 │ ..send_to..285  │ recv_from         │            278 │ ..recv_from..278  │
│ send_to      │       313 │ ...send_to..313 │ recv_from         │            303 │ ...recv_from..303 │
└──────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/lag-lead/

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        neighbor(syscall_type, -1) AS recv_syscall_type,
        neighbor(event_num, -1) AS recv_event_num,
        neighbor(event_buffer, -1) AS recv_event_buffer
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM my_db
        ORDER BY event_num ASC
        SETTINGS max_threads = 1, optimize_read_in_order = 0
    )
)
WHERE syscall_type = 'send_to'

Query id: 6295502c-6dff-4e8e-a87c-a015f8b69c30

┌─syscall_type─┬─event_num─┬─event_buffer────┬─recv_syscall_type─┬─recv_event_num─┬─recv_event_buffer─┐
│ send_to      │       285 │ ..send_to..285  │ recv_from         │            278 │ ..recv_from..278  │
│ send_to      │       313 │ ...send_to..313 │ recv_from         │            303 │ ...recv_from..303 │
└──────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to achieve this without using window functions ? Seems like their support is experimental for the moment

Comment: I've updated my answer. And Window functions are not experimental any more. I'll update the documentation right  now.

Comment: Thanks again for the update, have the samue issue as with the windows function, memory limit (for query) exceeded, is there a way to optimize this ?

Comment: No way. It's not MPP/OLAP task. CH unable to handle it.

Comment: So what would be the solution in this case? the  table contains more than 1 million records..

Comment: I suggest python